# CMD batch file for user profile migration

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I am working on a refresh project, and I am rebuilding and swapping out a lot of computers.  When doing a reimage, I have a script I can run which will copy the Desktop, Favorites, and Documents from all user profiles to a network share.

What I don't have yet, is a script for hardware replacements (vs a reimage) that will transfer data directly from the old computer to the new one.  As with my other script, I need it to transfer data from the Desktop, Favorites, and Documents folders for all user directories present on the old machine.  If I wanted to go a step further, I might exclude specific user profiles such as Public, Default, my own profile, etc, but a more basic script would still work.

I have done some batch scripting on my own, but I'm not sure what the syntax needs to be to have it cycle through all the user profiles on a remote machine.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
@echo off

Set /p remotepc=Enter remote hostname: 

for /D %%D in ("\\%remotepc%\USERS\*") do (xcopy \\%remotepc%\Users\%%~fD\Desktop "C:\Users\%%~nxD\Desktop" /H /E /Y /K /I /R /C)
for /D %%D in ("\\%remotepc%\USERS\*") do (xcopy \\%remotepc%\Users\%%~fD\Documents "C:\Users\%%~nxD\Documents" /H /E /Y /K /I /R /C)
for /D %%D in ("\\%remotepc%\USERS\*") do (xcopy \\%remotepc%\Users\%%~fD\Favorites "C:\Users\%computername%\%%~nxD\Favorites" /H /E /Y /K /I /R /C)
pause
```

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add that code. It is not readable in a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to format it correctly.  I have the code on individual lines, but as soon as I save the comment, it crams it all together like that.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You can't in a comment. That's why it should be in the question. Paste in the question, select the code and press <ctrl><k> to format as code. See See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I added the code to the original question above.

Comment: Almost right. You don't need the backticks. I've fixed it for you :)

Comment: I would suggest using Microsoft's USMT - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825256.aspx

Comment: I have heard of it, but I am not familiar with USMT and have never used it.  Is it better suited for migrating a few hundred computers at a time, or can it be used to migrate user profiles with as little as 1-10 computers at a time?  Also, does it require anything to be set up on the back end, or is it simply tools that can be run from any computer?  Especially if it can be run such that the user data is seamlessly migrated prior to their first login, that would be very helpful.